# jquery change placeholder attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this this table

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#f05_0002').change(function() {

    if ($("#f05_0002").val() == "OFF TRACK") {
      $("#f06_0002").attr("placeholder", "Please state what's not achieved, recommendations to be achieved");
    };

    if ($("#f05_0002").val() == "ON TRACK") {
      $("#f06_0002").attr("placeholder", "Please state the exact achievement");
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="t-Report-report" summary="S1 - 2017">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">Status</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="JAN_WEEK1">Week</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0002" id="f05_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0002">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
<option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0002" id="f06_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0002"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0003" id="f05_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0003">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0003" id="f06_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0003"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0004" id="f05_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0004">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0004" id="f06_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0004"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

what i want to achieve is that when i change the value of "Status" it updates the placeholder attr value of the week, i have tried this code but discovered that i have to repeat it for each row which is not a good idea

Comment: I encourage you to better indent your code.

Comment: try with `.prop` - but the if statement might not be being met

Comment: There was an extra `});` in your JS code. Not sure if your code is like that or something messed up while you pasted it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to repeat the code Just write the generic code like this .we can traverse the DOM element like this `$(this).closest("tr").find('textarea').attr("placeholder")`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('select').change(function() {

  if ($(this).val() =="OFF TRACK") {
      
     $(this).closest("tr").find('textarea').attr("placeholder","Please state what's not achieved, recommendations to be achieved");
   }

  if ($(this).val() =="ON TRACK") {
 
    $(this).closest("tr").find('textarea').attr("placeholder","Please state the exact achievement");

  }

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="t-Report-report" summary="S1 - 2017">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS" >Status</th>
<th class="t-Report-colHead"  align="center"  id="JAN_WEEK1" >Week</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
<label for="f05_0002" id="f05_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
<select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select "  id="f05_0002">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
<option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
</select>
</td>
<td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1">
<label for="f06_0002" id="f06_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
<textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea "  id="f06_0002"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0003" id="f05_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select "  id="f05_0003">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0003" id="f06_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea "  id="f06_0003"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0004" id="f05_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select "  id="f05_0004">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0004" id="f06_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea "  id="f06_0004"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your answers, they all work for me

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it's useful for future user reference @GeorgeS.

Answer (score 1):

A way you can do this is by using the `$('select[id^="f05_000"]')`.

It will select all `select` that has an `id` that starts by `f05_000`.

Then we can get the last part of the `id` (000#) with `var id = $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1]`

and last select the textarea with `$("#f06_" + id)`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[id^="f05_000"]').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split('_')[1];
    if ($(this).val() == "OFF TRACK") {
      $("#f06_" + id).attr("placeholder", "Please state what's not achieved, recommendations to be achieved");
    };

    if ($(this).val() == "ON TRACK") {
      $("#f06_" + id).attr("placeholder", "Please state the exact achievement");
    };

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="t-Report-report" summary="S1 - 2017">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">Status</th>
      <th class="t-Report-colHead" align="center" id="JAN_WEEK1">Week</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0002" id="f05_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0002">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
<option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
</select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0002" id="f06_0002_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0002"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0003" id="f05_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0003">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0003" id="f06_0003_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0003"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1_STATUS">
        <label for="f05_0004" id="f05_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <select name="f05" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--select " id="f05_0004">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="OFF TRACK" >Off Track</option>
            <option value="ON TRACK" >On Track</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="t-Report-cell" headers="JAN_WEEK1">
        <label for="f06_0004" id="f06_0004_LABEL" class="u-VisuallyHidden"></label>
        <textarea name="f06" rows="15" cols="35" wrap="VIRTUAL" class="u-TF-item u-TF-item--textarea " id="f06_0004"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: i was about to suggest either add a class to all of the common elements and apply the jquery function or the way you suggested.

Comment: @Rajesh I'm writing it as we speak

Comment: An answer without explanation is incomplete and will attract downvotes. Please make sure, you add proper explanation before posting. Have a good day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your row structure `<tr>` will be identical you can try below generic code which make use of `class` instead of `id`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.u-TF-item--select').change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() =="OFF TRACK") {
            //find the parent tr and then look for element with class u-TF-item--textarea
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".u-TF-item--textarea").attr("placeholder","Please state what's not achieved, recommendations to be achieved");
        };

        if ($(this).val() =="ON TRACK") {
            $(this).closest("tr").find(".u-TF-item--textarea").attr("placeholder","Please state the exact achievement");
        };

    });

});
```